# Move MySQL PostMeta table rows out of wp_postmeta and into new table by Date

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am managing a woocommerce store where the wp_postmeta table is getting out of control with 800k rows and growing on a daily basis. I would like to build a query that would allow me to move meta_id rows that have the same post_id where _customer_user = '0' where and where '_paid_date' is before a certain date (lets say 3 months?). These are guest checkout orders and not tied to a user account therefore I would like to archive them and create a custom post type to manipulate the data.

The new table would just be a clone of the postmeta table with a different name of course.

[image: screenshot of table]

This is all I got so far:

```
SELECT `meta_id` FROM `can_postmeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` = '_customer_user' AND `meta_value` = '0'
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean a website of all entries for guest customer, you need to remove entries in the table `wp_woocommerce_order_items` (link to the order_id), `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` (link with order_item_id). Same for `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens` and `wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta`.

I don't know, if you want to use a php script or sql request to do the job, but here is an little script to export a customer orders. Maybe it can give you some idea.

```
$filename = 'order_bu.json';
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'shop_order',
    'post_status'=> 'wc-completed',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
    'post_author' => 0
);

$orders = new WP_Query($args);

foreach($orders->posts as $order){
    echo $order->ID . ' | '.$order->post_status . '<br/>';
     $order_metas = get_post_meta($order->ID);
     $orders_metas[] = get_post_meta($order->ID);

     $order_stack[] = array($order, $orders_metas);
            //wp_delete_post($order->ID);

}

$json = json_encode($order_stack);

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    if (fwrite($handle, $json) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($json) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for an sql statement. But I appreciate the heads up on the other tables I will need to modify.

Comment: if you look to these tables you will find the differents lines of the order, not so important, but require the oder_meta_id to be deleted. I'm not an expert in sql statement but a lot code use JOIN, you may have a look to the woocommerce source code. Hope you'll find !